# print all matches of re.finditer (python)

Tags: python, regex

I am reading a PDF file (on one script using PyPDF2) and on this one using (tika).
In both, I have a problem with `re.finditer`.
I'll have a line of code like this:

```
bank_pattern = '^.* (Bank|bank|BANK).*$'
bank = re.finditer(bank_pattern, text)
print('Here should be the bank name:')
print(bank)
print('')

for match in bank:
    print(match)
```

And I get following:

```
Here should be the bank name:
<callable_iterator object at 0x0000020BA86B4430>
```

Can someone help me understand why doesn't it show the matches?
(I am trying to get the whole line where BANK, bank or Bank are mentioned - before and after the match)

P.S. read PDF part with banks:

```
Intermediary Bank (USD): censored,
New York, USA; SWIFT: censored 
Intermediary Bank (EUR): censored,
Frankfurt, Germany; SWIFT: censored
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `re.findall` here with the pattern `^.*\bbank\b.*$`:

```py
inp = """Intermediary Bank (USD): censored,
New York, USA; SWIFT: censored 
Intermediary Bank (EUR): censored,
Frankfurt, Germany; SWIFT: censored"""

lines = re.findall(r'^.*\bbank\b.*$', inp, flags=re.I|re.M)
print(lines)
```

This prints:

```
['Intermediary Bank (USD): censored,', 'Intermediary Bank (EUR): censored,']
```

Comment: Thank! This worked and helped with the rest of the code too. '\b \b'  is used to match regardless of capital or lowercase letters, right?

Comment: The `\b` are word boundaries, which ensure that we match the entire word bank only.